# Setting Reminders in Windows Phone 7 & 8 to Go Off Every Other Day

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, reminders

In my application I'm using the reminders service to supply reminders to the user, which prompts them to do something.
I am using the following code to do this:

```
if (date > DateTime.Now)
{
    Reminder r = new Reminder(fileTitle);
    r.Title = fileTitle;
    r.Content = fileContent;
    r.BeginTime = date;

    ScheduledActionService.Add(r);
}
```

However this only goes off once. I have tried setting the `ExpirationTime` to a certain value, but this repeats the reminder every day.

Does anyone know how to set a reminder to fire every other day?

(In addition it would be good to know how to set reminders for certain days of the week, but the every other day part is the main issue at the moment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case I would suggest storing the time the alarm should go off. You would store this information in either the application settings or in a file. When the user first asks for the reminder to be scheduled, continue what you are doing, and then also save the time for the alarm. You may want to also ask the user when they want the alarm to stop and save that as well.

To ensure that the alarm goes off every other day, you will need to add a [background agent](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Agent-Sample-02f0087b) to your application. In the agent is an OnInvoke method. In this method you will check to see if the alarm is scheduled. If it is then you have nothing to do. If it is not, then schedule it for the following day. Agents fire about every 30 minutes, so 99% of the time your agent fires, the alarm/reminder will already be scheduled.

Here is the code to place in your OnInvoke method

```
string fileTitle = "Foo";
string fileContent = "Bar";
var action = ScheduledActionService.Find(fileTitle);
if (action == null)
{
    // shouldn't be null if it was already added from the app itself.
    // should get the date the user actually wants the alarm to go off.
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);
    action = new Reminder(fileTitle) { Title = fileTitle, Content = fileContent, BeginTime = date };
}
else if (action.IsScheduled == false)
{
    ScheduledActionService.Remove(fileTitle);
    // most likely fired today, add two days to the begin time.
    // best to also add some logic if BeginTime.Date == Today
    action.BeginTime = action.BeginTime.AddDays(2);
}
ScheduledActionService.Add(action);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`RecurrenceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.schedulednotification.recurrencetype%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to a [`RecurrenceInterval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.recurrenceinterval%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) value. Unfortunately for you, there is nothing currently available for a custom schedule (i.e. every other day).

Another duh! by Microsoft here really.